# How to run an rscript with parameters from C#

Tags: c#, r

I am trying to run an R script using Rscript.exe from C#. The R script has arguments. How to invoke it? R script has a lot of optional parameters. Passing named parameters or key vlue pairs would be better.
I don't know how to pass parameters. Here's what I tried.

```
  [Fact]
    public void CEP_Abbreviated_SystemTest()
    {
        using (Process myProcess = new Process())
        {
            //(UseShellExecute) refers to a graphical shell 
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string dllPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            var digitalPlatformPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath), @"..\..\..\..\..\..\");
            var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dllPath), @"..\..\..\..\..\..\", "lib", "R-3.6.1", "bin", "Rscript.exe");
            var arg = Path.Combine(digitalPlatformPath, "DP.RPackages", "ClientEngagementPipeline", "exec", "CEP_Main.R");
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
            myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            //myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{arg} --tokens env.shruti --cluster cluster.local --localDir C:/Users/ShrutiKulkarni/Documents/1_DP/CEP/Winn/Job1 --releaseVersion 2.2 --scenarioConfigName ScenarioConfiguration_1MA.csv --newScenarioVersion Test_Winn --overwrite true --portfolioImporterFile C:/Users/ShrutiKulkarni/Documents/1_DP/CEP/Winn/Job1/ReadOnly_Files/ImporterFiles/PPA_OneRowWithDevGenFile-Valid_Solar.csv";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{arg} ";
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();

            Assert.True(myProcess.ExitCode != -1, myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself.
            // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it
            // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
            // from this application using the Kill method.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello. Le me know if you're interested in alternative solutions. There are script languages that can do statistical computations that can be executed within the .NET runtime (example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Waher.Script/), with access to .NET classes/methods/data, without the need to start separate processes. Can you share your R script?

Comment: Not looking for an alternative to r script. Alternative implementations in C# are fine.